# Erro Stack smashing detected em C

Tags: c, stack

Alguém poderia me ajudar na seguinte questão:

Elabore um programa que preencha uma matriz 6x4 com números inteiros, calcule e mostre quantos elementos dessa matriz são maiores que 30 e, em seguida, monte uma segunda matriz com os elementos diferentes de 30. No lugar do número 30, da segunda matriz, coloque o número zero.

Fiz o seguinte codigo porém esta dando o seguinte erro: **stack smashing detected:  terminated** e não estou conseguindo saber o porque.Estou usando o Netbeans como IDE.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define L 2
#define C 2

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int matriz[L][C], mat2[L][C];
    int i, j, pL = 0, pC = 0, contMaior30 = 0, contIgual30 = 0, contDif30 = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            printf("M[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i][j]);
        }
    }

    //Laço para fazer a verificação dos valores digitados
    for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            if (matriz[i][j] <= 30) {
                if (matriz[i][j] == 30) {
                    mat2[pL][pC] = 0;
                } else if (matriz[i][j] < 30) {
                    mat2[pL][pC] = matriz[i][j];
                }
                contDif30++;
                pL++;
                pC++;
            }

           //Contar a quantidade de números maiores que 30 
            else {
                contMaior30++;
            }
        }
    }

    //Não sei como controlar a impressão de segunda matriz
    printf("\nImpressão do segundo vetor: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("\tM2: %d \n", mat2[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**O erro indica que está passar dos limites da matriz, e escrever em zonas de memória que passam dos limites.**

Isso dá-se no `for` que constroi a segunda matriz:

```
if (matriz[i][j] <= 30) {
    if (matriz[i][j] == 30) {
        mat2[pL][pC] = 0; // <--- aqui
    } else if (matriz[i][j] < 30) {
        mat2[pL][pC] = matriz[i][j]; // <-- e aqui
    }
    contDif30++;
    pL++;
    pC++;
}
```

Antes de mais a comparação é estranha pois começa por testar se `matriz[i][j] <= 30` e depois lá dentro volta a testar `matriz[i][j] < 30`. Mas se o elemento for `<=30` aumenta o `pL` e o `pC`, e estes dois são utilizados como indices da matriz:

```
mat2[pL][pC] = matriz[i][j];
//    ^---^
```

Logo no seu exemplo de matriz `2x2`, em que as posições validas vao de `0` a `1`, se apanhar três elementos menores que `30` o `pL` e o `pC` já vão em `3`. Isto vai resultar numa atribuição equivalente a:

```
mat2[3][3] = matriz[i][j];
```

**Que está incorreta pois passa os limites da matriz, que vão de 0 a 1.**

Em vez disso sugiro que faça antes assim:

```
//Laço para fazer a verificação dos valores digitados
for (i = 0; i < L; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < C; j++) {
        if (matriz[i][j] == 30){
            mat2[i][j] = 0; //atribui em mat2 com base no i, j também
            contIgual30++;
        }
        else {
            contDif30++;
            mat2[i][j] = matriz[i][j]; //atribui em mat2 com base no i, j também
            if (matriz[i][j] > 30){
                contMaior30++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As atribuições em `mat2` são feitas com `[i][j]` para colocarem o elemento na mesma posição da matriz resultante.

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/FIdR7x)

Edit:

Para mostrar na saída apenas os valores menores ou iguais a `30` precisa de adicionar um `if` na parte que mostra:

```
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        if (mat2[i][j] <= 30){ // <--este
            printf("\tM2: %d \n", mat2[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/G7RUCj)

Comment: Brigadão cara, mas ainda não entendi como vou fazer o controle do for que irá imprimir a segunda matriz. Poderia me ajudar nisso tbm?

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueDomingues Sem problema. Qual controle ? A impressão da segunda matriz não está como pretende ? O que está a faltar ?

Comment: Para poder fazer a contagem dos valores <= 30. Porque criei um matriz 2x2 apenas para testes, o exercício solicita uma 6x4. No caso precisaria de uma variavel para fazer a contagem desses valores, para na hora de imprimir não imprimir toda matriz2;

Comment: Não sei se ficou claro.

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueDomingues O tamanho da matriz não influencia na lógica. E a contagem dos maiores que 30, menores que 30 e iguais a 30 já está a ser feita. Qual contagem é que ficou a faltar ? "para na hora de imprimir não imprimir toda matriz2" - quais são os que não é para imprimir ? Podia dar um exemplo de uma impressão correta ?

Comment: Entrada: 50, 6, 1 ,30

| Saida esperada: 6,1,0

| Saida obitida: 654948592,6,1,0

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueDomingues Mas o `50` não aparece na saida porque é maior que `30` é isso ?

Comment: Queria que imprimisse some os valores menores ou igual a 30 (onde será substituído por 0)

Comment: Extamente, queria achar um jeito que pulasse a posição que esta o 50 e imprimisse os demais

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueDomingues Já editei a resposta para contemplar essa parte também. Veja se era aquilo que estava à procura.

Comment: Exatamente, ia te falar que ja havia resolvido, fiz a mesma coisa que você fez.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda cara e desculpa a amolaçao haha

Comment: @ThiagoHenriqueDomingues Sem problema. Estamos cá para ajudar :)